# What are possible ways to access activity's or fragment's onRequestPermissionsResult from other classes

Tags: java, android, class, android-permissions

I am trying to create helper class snippet for *Android Runtime Permissions*, in this example I have two classes `MyActivity` and `BoilerPlate`. `MyActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` and `FragmentActivity` implements `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` interface which has a callback method `onRequestPermissionsResult(param1, param2, param3)`. My `BoilerPlate` class has a instance of `MyActivity`.

**Class MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private BoilerPlate boilerPlate;

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        boilerPlate = new BoilerPlate(this);
    }

    //...

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, String[] grantResults){
        super(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

**Class FragmentActivity**

```
public class FragmentActivity implements OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    //...

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, String[] grantResults){

    }

    //...
}
```

**Class BoilerPlate**

```
public class BoilerPlate {

    private MyActivity mActivity;

    BoilerPlate(MyActivity activity){
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `FragmentActivity`, `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` are not in scope of modification. Only I can modify is `BoilerPlate` and to some limit `MyActivity`.

**Question:** Can I somehow use instance of `MyActivity` inside `BoilerPlate` to access params of `onRequestPermissionsResult(p1, p2, p3)`, whenever callback is triggered.

**P.S** I know I can create a method in `BoilerPlate` with params and call that method through instance of `boilerPlate` in `MyActivity`.

**Class MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private BoilerPlate boilerPlate;

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);

        boilerPlate = new BoilerPlate(this);
    }

    //...

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, String[] grantResults) {
        super(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        boilerPlate.getResults(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

**Class BoilerPlate**

```
public class BoilerPlate {

    private MyActivity mActivity;

    BoilerPlate(MyActivity activity){
        this.mActivity = activity;
        // do something with activity.
    }

    public void getResults(int requestCode, String[] permissions, String[] grantResults) {
        // do anything with request, permissions, grantResults.
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to add an X, Y and Z

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote?

Comment: what about making `private A a;` `protected`?

Comment: @Omkar Well I downvoted because I hate these ABC, XYZ, H, I, `abc()` questions. Use some meaningful names, that code reads horribly. Also I'm cranky because I haven't had my morning coffee.

Comment: I also downvoted for the same reason as @Kayaman (it's noon here and I did have two cups of tea already0

Comment: @Omkar i´m with @Kayaman. The question itself is well formated and quite good, but due to all this one letter `A`, `B`, `C` things pretty unreadable

Comment: Give me time I will convert to something meaningful.

Comment: I see no better solution than the `xyz` method (except for the method name :-) ). What’s wrong with that? Or put another way, what else do you wish to obtain that your own solution doesn’t provide?

Comment: Now it's more meaningful?

Comment: Yes, please update your answer with meaningful method names, as I did.

Answer (score 1):

I dont get what the point of overriding a method is when you just call its super version.

But anyway: you solve your problem by adding another callback. In other words: your class B holds an "a" object. And somehow, other code will be calling abc() on that "a" object.

If the enclosing "b" object wants to know about that, the only way is: class A allows class B to register another callback upon creation. So whenever abc() is called on "a"; that "a" calls b.xyz(). ( xzy being the callback method within class B).

If you find that confusing; well, that perfectly reflects my feelings about your question. But seriously; I hope this helps.

Comment: Question is now more clear, I guess. Please update the answer?